# Backbone : access model's data from collection's remove method

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am looking for a way to remove one of model's data sets by using collection's remove method.
But it doesn't seem to work in this way. Is there any way to remove a data in model from collection's method?

here is my code.

```
       helloWorldModel.set({things: value});
       helloWorldCollection.add([
         {things: helloWorldModel.get("things")}
       ]);
       helloWorldCollection.remove(?????????);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to the object you add to the collection to remove it; something like the following is a possible solution. Though I would create an actual model containing the slimmed down version of your other model:

```
helloWorldModel.set({things: value});
obj = {things: helloWorldModel.get("things")}
helloWorldCollection.add(obj);
helloWorldCollection.remove(obj);
```